Defining hasMany self-associations in sequelize v7
export default class Folder extends Model<InferAttributes<Folder>, InferCreationAttributes<Folder>> {
  
  @Attribute(DataTypes.INTEGER)
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;

  @Attribute(DataTypes.STRING)
  @NotNull
  declare title: string;

  @Attribute(DataTypes.INTEGER)
  declare parentId: number;

  declare parent?: NonAttribute<Folder>;
  declare children?: NonAttribute<Folder[]>;

  @HasMany(() => Folder, {
    // as: 'children',
    foreignKey: 'parentId',
    inverse: {
      as: 'parent'
    },
  })

For the HasMany association, if I don't include as: 'children' property, I get the following errors from sequelize :

SequelizeAssociationError: Defining HasMany association "parent" from _Folder to _Folder failed
Caused by: SequelizeAssociationError: Both options "as" and "inverse.as" must be defined for hasMany self-associations, and their value must be different.

However, if I include the as: 'children' property, I get the following errors from typescript & sequelize :

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'as' does not exist in type 'Omit<HasManyOptions<string, "id" | "title" | "parented">, "as">'.ts(2353)
Error: The "as" option is not allowed when using association decorators. The name of the decorated field is used as the association name.

How do I resolve this & get the self-association to work ?
